# pass -next option to spring JobLauncher

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am executing the batch job programatically using `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher`

In my code, I have statement like

```
JobExecution result = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
```

Most of the batch jobs I have run with parameters, but one of my batch job does not take any parameters. So, I have set up that job with `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer`

In order to user incrementer, I have to provide -next option to JobLauncher. How do I pass my jobLauncher this -next parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I dont found any solution how to add "next" param in code. Instead of this you can put current time as param:

```
Map<String, JobParameter> jobParameterMap = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
jobParameterMap.put("date", new JobParameter(new Date()));
JobExecution exec = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(jobParameterMap));
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an equivalent on the `JobLauncher` to increment the `JobParameters`.  The way to launch a job this way is using the `JobOperator#startNextInstance(String jobName)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I faced the same problem and this is how I solved it:

```
// Calls the incrementer attached to your job
JobParameters incrementedJobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder(jobExplorer)
    .getNextJobParameters(job)
    .toJobParameters();

// Add/Override new parameters
JobParameters newJobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder(incrementedJobParameters)
    .addString("PARAM1", "param1")
    .toJobParameters();

// Launch job
jobLauncher.run(job, newJobParameters);
```